# Gathering a user's news feed with Koala (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, facebook, omniauth, koala

I want to pull in a user's newsfeed after they have authenticated. I am using the [Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) but if I call `get_connection('me', 'feed')` it only returns the last three posts on my wall. I want the last ~100 posts (or since post 1234567) that would show up on the user's home page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all posts during a certain time period using FQL.  Here is an example that should get you started:

```
@feed = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.token)
to = Time.now.to_i
yest = 1.day.ago.to_i
@feed.fql_query("SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, likes FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time > #{yest} AND created_time < #{to} AND type = 80 
AND strpos(attachment.href, "youtu") >= 0")

require 'koala'
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new("YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN")
@graph.fql_query("SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time > START_TIME AND created_time < END_TIME LIMIT 10")
```

Code borrowed from [here](http://pastebin.com/XJDGaJU8).